# C++ lldb debug with input file

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm attempting to debug my program with lldb beacuse I'm getting a segmentation fault when entering a specific input that should would. I give my program the input through a text file and normally I write this command to run it:

```
./program <tests/test1.maze> program.out
```

How do I run the debugger whilst still passing in the file? Haven't been able to find anything that says how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
(lldb) process launch -i <file>
```

Use the help command to view all available options.

```
(lldb) help process launch
```